# How to find with JavaScript only two out of three instances of the same html class?

Tags: javascript, html

I have three `<div>` elements with the same class of "child". Imagine that I cannot add any other class to the `<div>`. How can I find only two of those `div`elements (second and third) with JavaScript? (the code below is just for better understanding of what I mean - mind that `<div>` elements with the same class are not siblings).

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="new">
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a selector and array magic: `var els = Array.from(document.querySelector('.child')).splice(1)`.

Comment: @RobG You meant `slice`, right?

Comment: $(".child").not(":eq(0)"); dont waste your time with vanilla js if you can use something stable (use jQuery)

Comment: @JohnWeisz thank you for sharing your opinion, *"for example use jQuery", my intention was not to force yet your comment is kinda forcing react and angular over jQuery. Let me share my opinion (react and angular have too much sugar) but still you use various tools for various tasks, that is my point

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir What I meant by the question was to get the last two elements with class="child" not looking at the level they are nested. Just taking all of them in consideration.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I corrected the description as it could have been obscure. I will check the answers when I have more time.

Comment: @Bergi— *slice* works too, but either will do as the OP isn't interested in the original array. For those touting jQuery: it isn't tagged or asked for and is [*6 to 12 times slower*](https://jsperf.com/slicing-children/1) than POJS, depending on the browser.

Comment: @bakrall Does this code snipped appear just once on the page? If not, the selected answer will not work.

Comment: @bakrall Actually, it will work at least once, but after that, it is a toss-up.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge -- *"Does this code snipped appear just once on the page? If not, the selected answer will not work."* -- This is incorrect. [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName#Syntax) can be used on any DOM element, in which case the search is constrained to descendants of that element.

Comment: @JohnWeisz Without answering the first question "Does this code snipped appear just once on the page", I'm not certain about the value of your comment. Of course `.getElementsByClassName()` can be used on any DOM element. That is not at issue here. The issue is that indexes 1 and 2 will point to the same two elements everytime if the above code snippet appears only once on the page. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @JohnWeisz Correction: The issue is that indexes 1 and 2 will point to the same two elements everytime if the above code snippet appears *more than once* on the page. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge -- Sure, in which case you would only search a particular tree in the DOM, not its entirety. However, this is not part of this question.

Comment: @JohnWeisz It is implied by the definition of CSS, that CSS classes may be used over and over again on a page. If you ignore the possibility and subsequent problem of multiple code snippets, you are ignoring the fundamental tenants of code reuse and flexibility. Your solution, as shown, only works in one scenario (one HTML code snippet). My solution works in the general case, yours is limited to a specific case. A specific case answer only serves you once. A general case answer servers you now and into the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM defines a [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) function, which returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object:

```
var elementsWithChildClass = document.getElementsByClassName("child");
```

In your case, this will return the 3 `div` elements with the *"child"* className. You can then access a given element on this list using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) syntax, for example:

```
var secondElem = elementsWithChildClass[1];
var thirdElem = elementsWithChildClass[2];
```

In your case, both of these objects will be [HTMLDivElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement) instances (which inherits from [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)).

> **Note:** the index of the HTMLCollection object is zero-based, which means the first element is accessed using `[0]`, second element using `[1]`, and so on.

Comment: This answer is incomplete because it will only work one time on a page. If you use indexes 1 and 2 all of the time, you'll always get the same values.

Comment: I am confused as to why this has been chosen as the answer, when clearly it only works in one scnario (gathering all `.chlid` class divs on the entire page).

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge -- *"This answer is incomplete because it will only work one time on a page"* -- Wrong. `getElementsByClassName` can be used on any DOM element, in which case that element is the root of the search. This is explained in the linked documentation.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge -- Also, I'm pretty confident OP can figure out how to change two numeric literals, or take the `length` property into consideration (since it is also explained in the linked documentation).

Comment: @Melinda -- *"clearly it only works in one scnario"* -- Incorrect. `getElementsByClassName` can be used on any element, in which case the search is constrained to descendants of that element. This wasn't part of the question, but is explained in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

Comment: @JohnWeisz Assumptions are not the issue here. If the code snippet appears only once on the page, this will work. If the code snippet appears more than once, indexs 1 and 2 will be the same every time. This is why my answer is better. My answer allows for the targeting of a parent, limiting the scope of nodes collected by `.getElementsByClassName()`. Also, my answer provides for a separation of DOM access and return results processing. My answer is more general, modular, and flexible.  This answer relies on an assumption (the code snipped will only appear one time), mine does not.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge -- Let me repeat, rephrase, and emphasize that: `getElementsByClassName` _itself_ can be used to target a parent.

Comment: @JohnWeisz I understand your thoughts, but Anthony Rutledge has a point.

Comment: @Melinda -- That's beside the point -- it's simply incorrect that the above API call would only work one time on a page. See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sLyg492h/).

Comment: @JohnWeisz But Mr. Weisz, you are not doing that in your answer. You are targeting the document root. If the code snippet appears on the page more than once, indexs 1 and 2 will point to the same elements each time you run it. There is a better way.

Comment: @Melinda -- Correct, and considering the question says *"I have **three** `<div>` elements with the same class of 'child'"*, I stand corrected.

Comment: @JohnWeisz No one would argue this will work if the entire code snippet appears just once, but the point of CSS classes is to re-use them in many places. It would be a myopic assumption to assume that this snipped will only appear once. AnthonyRutledge's solution eliminates the problem of multiple code snippets and is a much better, reliable, and comprehensive solution.

Comment: @Melinda -- I would respectfully disagree that it would be a "better", or more "comprehensive" solution, considering these are subjective terms all up to debate and use-case (whether useless or redundant in context or not). More reliable? Sure.

Comment: @JohnWeisz Perhaps you did not get to the bottom of my answer? It is a one-liner inside of a function with four arguments. It is very reusable, especially if one attached it to a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

```
var slice = function(elements, start, end) {
    var sliced = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements, start, end);
    return sliced;
};

var totalChildElem = document.getElementsByClassName("child");

if (totalChildElem.length)
{
    var myChildElem = slice(totalChildElem,1);
}
```

Comment: Good attempt, but there is a logic error. `var totalChildElem` is being forced to hold *all* `.child` divs, instead of just a subset from the DOM. Remember, only the 2nd and 3rd nodes are required. Your solution requires the implementer to know the eventual index number of each `.child` element. What if there are 10, 50, 100, etc? Do you really want to count that out? No. It would be better to target a parent node that contains the three `.child` divs.

Comment: This solution has the benefit of keeping the range that you are trying to target generic (by defining parameters, `start` and `end`), instead of hard coding the range in. But, the real problem is narrowing the scope so that you only need to deal with three nodes at time.

Comment: In effect, the HTML sample is not guaranteed to exist only once on the page. Frequently, as you probably know, HTML snippets repeat.

Comment: Also, this code should be modular and less dependent on the global namespace.

Answer (score -1):

**Revised Question**: How can I to get the last two elements with `class="child"`, not looking at the level they are nested (second and third) with *JavaScript*?

You do not need jQuery to do this.
An answer that works all the way down to at least ES3 might look like this. In this case, supplying a `parentId` allows you to target groups of three `.child` classes, instead of making JavaScript collect all `.child` classes.

```
function get2ndAnd3rdClassNodes(parentId, targetClass)
{
    var targets = [];
    var nodes = document.getElementById(parentId).getElementsByClassName(targetClass);

    for(var i = 1, length = nodes.length; i < length; ++i)
    {
         target[i - 1] = nodes[i];
    }

    nodes = null;
    return targets;
}
```

A more modern answer might look like this:

```
function get2ndAnd3rdClassNodes(parentId, targetClass)
{
    var nodes = document.getElementById(parentId).getElementsByClassName(targetClass);   
    return Array.prototype.splice.call(nodes, 1, 2);
}
```

Sometimes it is advantageous to separate DOM access from the code that manipulates the values returned from the DOM. In that case, the function could work with nodes, instead of starting with an id (and target classname). `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a nodeList, which is an array-like object, but an object nonetheless. In order to use JavaScript array methods with it, you need to, in effect, cast it to an array.

```
function get2ndAnd3rdClassNodes(nodes, targetClass)
{
    nodes = nodes.getElementsByClassName(targetClass);   
    return Array.prototype.splice.call(nodes, 1, 2);
}
```

Or, in one line:

```
function get2ndAnd3rdClassNodes(nodes, targetClass)
{
    return Array.prototype.splice.call(nodes.getElementsByClassName(targetClass), 1, 2);  
}
```

Finally, if you want to be able to target how many elements to get rid of in a flexible way:

```
function spliceClassNodes(nodes, targetClass, startIndex, nodesNeeded)
{
    var minNodes = startIndex + nodesNeeded;

    try
    {
        if(nodes.length < minNodes)
        {
            throw new RangeError('Only ' + nodes.length + ' received. Needed ' + minNodes + ' to process this nodeList correctly.');
        }

        return Array.prototype.splice.call(nodes.getElementsByClassName(targetClass), startIndex, nodesNeeded);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        if(e instanceof RangeError)
        {
            //Handle the problem. 
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Invoked as:

```
var childArray = spliceClassNodes(nodes, 'child', 1, 2);
```

Feel free to add this to a prototype.

Comment: This has the benefit of being reusable. You could add it to a prototype.